Refactoring .onDrop code into its own file does not compile
I have a View that has an Image and a .onDrop that modifies the Image.  The intent of the .onDrop is to allow the user to drag and drop an array of user file URLs onto the image. As each URL is processed the created image is displayed briefly in lieu of a status bar.  My code works using the @State vars but it is 40+ lines long and doesn't really belong in the View.  I tried to refactor it into a struct in its own file to encapsulate the .onDrop code but cannot even make it compile.  I have not been able to find an example on line. In the process, for the first time, I've learned how to crash a macBook!
This code works just as intended:
    .onDrop(of: [.fileURL], isTargeted: $isTargeted) { providers in
        // Empty the array before accepting new URLs
        imageList.removeAll()
        isNewDrop = true // reset in .tify
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        
        for provider in providers {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            _ = provider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { url, error in
                defer { dispatchGroup.leave() }
                
                if let url = url {
                    if url.isFileURL && url.pathExtension == "raw" {
                        thisImageBuilder = ImageBuilder() 
                    }
                    if !thisImageBuilder!.newFile(fileURL: url, isNewTransect: isNewDrop ) {
                        fatalError("Failed to build GCImage.")
                    }
                    // transect static vars now fully initialized
                    // display the image
                    imageList.append(thisImageBuilder!)
                    currentDatum = thisImageBuilder! // UI sugar for viewer
                    imageCaption = thisImageBuilder!.displayName
                    isNewDrop = false
                } else {
                    // TODO Handle non-file URLs (e.g., directories)
                    print("ImageView: Invalid URL: \(url)")
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                // TODO Handle any errors that occur during URL loading
                print("ImageView: Error loading URL: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } // load object ie D&D
        }  // for loop
        // all data read & processed
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { 
          // post-processing to display first image
          //  display first image & set indicies 
            isNewDrop = false 
            currentDatum = imageList.first  // display first image.
            imageCaption = currentDatum!.displayName
            isTargeted = false 
            maxImageIndex = imageList.count - 1
            thisImageIndex = 0 // first image of drop
        }
        return true //
    } // on drop


My "best" try at refactoring the code into a struct is below, it doesn't compile with the errors "Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter " for each parameter.
    import SwiftUI

    struct URLDropHandler {
    
        mutating func handleDroppedFiles(providers: [NSItemProvider], isNewDrop: inout Bool, imageCaption: inout String, isTargeted: inout Bool, thisImageIndex: inout Int, maxImageIndex: inout Int, imageList: inout [ImageBuilder]?, currentDatum: inout ImageBuilder?) {
        
        imageList?.removeAll()
        isNewDrop = true // reset in .notify

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        
        for provider in providers {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    _ = provider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { url, error in
                defer { dispatchGroup.leave() }
                
        if let url = url, url.isFileURL, url.pathExtension == "raw" {
        let thisImageBuilder = ImageBuilder()
        if !thisImageBuilder.newFile(fileURL: url, isNewTransect: isNewDrop) { // ERROR for each of the vars
            fatalError("Failed to build CGImage.")
        }
            imageList?.append(thisImageBuilder)
            currentDatum = thisImageBuilder // UI sugar for viewer
            imageCaption = thisImageBuilder.displayName
            isNewDrop = false
    } else {
        print("Invalid URL: \(url?.absoluteString ?? "nil")")
    }
        }
        } // for providers
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {. // ERROR for each of the vars
    isNewDrop = false // TODO verify this
    imageCaption = currentDatum?.displayName ?? ""
    isTargeted = false // TODO verify this
    thisImageIndex = 0 // first image of drop
    maxImageIndex = imageList?.count ?? 0 - 1
    currentDatum = imageList?.first  // display first image.
        }
        }
    }



Please consider turning this question into a minimal example.
I think your issue is due to @escaping not working with inout since the former is asynchronous and the latter is a synchronous operation. If you make this question reproducible I can give you a code-level correction :)

Are you sure that is the right way to do something asynchronous in a drop operation in the first place? Since onDrop is synchronous and you're inside a struct it has no lifetime.

@Stoic I delayed responding to your comment as I needed to think about how to provide a minimal working example.

After installing Sequoia and updating Xcode the rate at which the files are read in is so fast, 100 files in less than two seconds, I will attempt to simplify the code.  I still need to do something that will feed back to the calling View that there are new data.
